# Is there a solution to converting a nunjucks .njk file to a twig php file?

Tags: parsing, drupal, twig, nunjucks

Currently trying to find/build a process that allows me to take .njk files from USWDS and convert them into php twig files for a Drupal 8 project.

(Now, at this current point in time they are similar. So with a little tweaking you could easily make an .njk file into a twig file manually.)

However, automating the process is a bit harder, and researching the topic yields few results. Currently I've found this, https://github.com/shawnbot/meta-template. Which they may resume work on, but at the current time, it is a little broken.

So, does anyone know of a way to automate converting twig files from nunjucks/.njk files?

Comment: We have a design system library which contains Nunjucks templates and we would like to be able to use the same components from inside Twig templates.

Comment: @LeaHayes. Same for me